# Find the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $\tau(n)=35$. Find all solutions of $\sigma(n) = 35$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $\tau(n)=35$. Find all solutions of $\sigma(n)=35$.

Since $\tau(n)=(k_1+1)(k_2+1)\dots(k_n+1)$ where $n=p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\dots p_n^{k_n}$ then the smallest integer would be $2^{34}$ since $2$ is the smallest prime.

Now I am having trouble finding any solutions to $\sigma(n)=35$

$35 = \sigma(n) = \prod_{p^k ||\: n} \frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p-1}.$

Each factor $d$ in the product is an integer

If $d$ divides $n$ and $\frac{p^{k+1} - 1}{p-1} = d$ then $p^{k+1} = pd - (d - 1)$ which means $p$ divides $d-1$. So $p^k = d - \frac{d-1}{p}.$  Now the only divisors of $35$ are $5,7,35$ of which none work when substituted.

Comment: For $\tau(n) = 35$, $n = 2^{6}3^{4}$ is a smaller solution that the one you presented

Comment: Turn your argument into a proof that there are no solutions to $\sigma(n)=35$ and that will indisputably be the correct answer to "Find all solutions of $\sigma(n)=35$" (namely, that there are none).

Comment: $35=\sigma(n)\geq n+1$ so possible $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod{5}$ are impossible.

Comment: Alejopelaez thanks I jumped the gun on my solution I see now the mistake I made. Thanks also Minz your comment helped a lot.